# multi factor authentication to access a sharepoint site using c# console application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, multi-factor-authentication

I have been trying to access SP using MFA. I have been receiving a series of errors following the implementation. Does anyone have a source to an available cod with all necessary assemblies that I can download?

I tried the code implemented in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-csom-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-with-multi-factor-authentication-enabled
Installed Microsoft.SharePoint.Client , SharePointPnPCoreOnline and System.Drawing.Common.
Getting an error :
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I also tried the code from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/token-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/
Installed PnP.Framework and AppForSharePointOnlineWebToolKit
Getting an error : authenticationmanager' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments